# Flexed div shrinks beyond content size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

> Fiddle: [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/u925mam8/)

A normal card looks like this:

[image]

However, when the browser display is resized, it shrinks to this:

[image]

The HTML:

```css
#product-list {
    overflow-y : scroll !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body class="bg-faded h-100">

<!--This is where we insert the tabs-->
<div id="current-tab" style="" class="h-100 fixed-top">

<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-row m-0 p-0 h-100 w-100">
   
    <div id="products"
         class="bg-white d-flex flex-column">

        <!--Product List-->
        <div id="product-list"
             class="card-deck p-4 bg-light">
            <!--Product card-->
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <img class="card-img-top"
                     src="https://cbp.s3.amazonaws.com/img/0/0/4/8/4/5/tn050016-the-national-trouble-will-find-me-2x12-vinyl-g-3.png"
                     alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                        the card's content.</p>
                </div>

                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item "><b class="pl-0 pr-5">Price</b>₱200.00</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><b class="pl-0 pr-3">Quantity</b> 19</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="card-footer d-flex border-top-0 pl-4 pr-4">
                    <a href="#"
                       id="edit-product-button"
                       class="btn btn-outline-primary ml-auto w-50 mr-3">Modify</a>
                    <a href="#"
                       id="delete-product-button"
                       class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-auto w-50">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The entire application is on `position: fixed`, but `#product-list` should be scrollable so I added this:

```
#product-list {
    overflow-y : scroll !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I am using Boostrap 4.0.0 beta, running on Chrome.

Comment: You can use overflow: hidden;  text-overflow: ellipsis; if the text size in the card in para increases and u can show on hover the full text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `#product-list` and `.card` have a `display: flex;` property. Since `.card` is a direct child of `#product-list` and has a `display: flex` property it will fill the space allocated—but no more. Technically `.card` is at 100% height.

To fix this you need to do the following:

1. Remove `.card-deck` from `#product-list`.
2. Wrap all `.card` divs with `.card-deck`.
3. Change `.card`'s `height` property from `height: 100%;` to `min-height: 100%;`.

[In this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/6z8vrLqk/4/), I've made these changes and now `.card` works as desired.

Comment: This does not seem to fix the issue, would you mind adding the changes to a JSFiddle?

Comment: This fixes the card issue, but this breaks the card-deck `display: flex` property, which I need, because this dictates the appearance of multiple cards.

Comment: @Berry Remove the `.card-deck` class from `#products-list` div and replace `.product-list-wrapper` with `.card-deck`. My answer has been updated.

Comment: @Berry I should note that this doesn't fix your cards being inconsistent widths if you have an uneven amount. You'll have to mess with your `min-width`, `max-width`, and `flex` values on `.card`.